# Is there a command to output only part of a command result in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, text-processing

My question is, when we type a command with `grep` in terminal we get output along with the title:

For example:

```
lscpu | grep MHz
```

Will output:

```
CPU MHz:               1216.851
```

But what if I only want:

```
1216.851
```

As the output? Is there any other command to perform this task?

Comment: In addition to `awk`, also see `cut` and `sed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are other ways, the most straightforward would probably be [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
$ lscpu | grep MHz | awk '{print $3}'
2494.038
```

Or:

```
$ lscpu | grep MHz | awk '{print $NF}'
2494.038
```

`$3` represents the third field in the output (separated by any amount of whitespace). `$NF` represents the LAST field in the output, no matter how many fields there are.

You can also skip `grep` entirely and just do it all with `awk`:

```
$ lscpu | awk '/MHz/ { print $NF; exit }'
2494.038
```

As [@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) pointed out, GNU `grep` can also do this:

```
lscpu | grep --color=never -oP 'MHz:\s+\K.*'
```

But the other examples above are POSIX-friendly (although systems that have `lscpu` probably also have GNU `grep`).

Comment: Or, if you have GNU grep and you like PCRE regexes: `lscpu | grep -oP 'MHz:\s+\K.*'`